# Node.JS: Azure does not install new dependencies from package.json

Tags: node.js, azure

Azure doesn't install packages added to package.json

I recently added a new dependency to my app, **jsonminify**.

From my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "requirejs": ">=2.0.2",
  "express3-handlebars": "==0.5.0",
  "express": "==3.2.6",
  "twitter": "==0.2.5",
  "instagram-node": "==0.1.13",
  "superagent": "==0.15.7",
  "jsonminify": "==0.2.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "grunt": "~0.4.1",
  "matchdep": "~0.1.2",
  "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.1",
  "grunt-open": "~0.2.1",
  "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.7.0",
  "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.4.1"
}
```

From the output of `git push azure master`:

```
remote: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/requirejs/-/requirejs-2.1.8.tgz
remote: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express3-handlebars/-/express3-handlebars-0.5.0.tgz
remote: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/instagram-node/-/instagram-node-0.1.13.tgz
remote: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/superagent/-/superagent-0.15.7.tgz
remote: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-autoprefixer/-/grunt-autoprefixer-0.4.1.tgz
remote: npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/superagent/-/superagent-0.15.7.tgz
remote: npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/instagram-node/-/instagram-node-0.1.13.tgz
remote: npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express3-handlebars/-/express3-handlebars-0.5.0.tgz
remote: npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/requirejs/-/requirejs-2.1.8.tgz
remote: npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-autoprefixer/-/grunt-autoprefixer-0.4.1.tgz
```

Note Azure is not installing jsonminify, the new package.

How can I make Windows Azure install new packages?

Answer (score 1):

This was my own fault.

I updated package.json, but forgot that I am using npm shrinkwrap.

Re-running `npm shrinkwrap`, and committing the fix, sorted things out.